# Exportar dados de um listview para PDF

Tags: android, listview, pdf

Olá, pessoal! 
O que preciso para exportar dados de um listview no android para um documento PDF?
Gostaria de escrever um arquivo PDF com todos os dados contidos no listview.

Answer (score 0):

Facilmente crie um for loop para escrever cada valor do array usado no Listview.
Para criar e escrever em um pdf use este tutorial https://www.blueappsoftware.com/how-to-create-pdf-file-in-android/